# Bash script that checks for package dependencies and installs them if necessary

Tags: bash, linux, sh

I'm new to writing bash scripts and was wondering if I could get someone's advice on a part of the script I'm working on.

#### Intended purpose of code

Check if a package exists using `dpkg`, and if it doesn't, offer to install it for the user. This snippet is part of a larger script that installs a particular Conky configuration along with all of its dependencies with minimal effort from the user.

#### Concerns

- I feel as though there is a more elegant way to check if a package is installed using `dpkg` (code was found on Stack Overflow).
- Is there a better way of handling the (y/n) response?

Here is the code that I am using:

```
declare -a packages=("conky-all" "lm-sensors");

for i in "${packages[@]}"; do
    if [ $(dpkg-query -W -f='${Status}' $i 2>/dev/null | grep -c "ok installed") -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "$i is not installed, would you like to install it now? (Y/N)";
        read response
        if [ "$response" == "y" ] || [ "$response" == "Y" ]; then
            sudo apt-get install "$i";
        else
            echo "Skipping the installation of $i...";
            echo "Please note that this Conky configuration will not work without the $i package.";
        fi
    else
        echo "The $i package has already been installed.";
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of this:

> ```
>     if [ $(dpkg-query -W -f='${Status}' $i 2>/dev/null | grep -c "ok installed") -eq 0 ]; then
> ```

A better way to write the same thing:

```
    if ! dpkg-query -W -f='${Status}' $i 2>/dev/null | grep -q "ok installed"; then
```

Instead of this:

> ```
>         if [ "$response" == "y" ] || [ "$response" == "Y" ]; then
> ```

A simpler way to write is:

```
        if [[ $response == [yY]* ]]; then
```

This is not example the same. It will match anything that starts with "y" or "Y". If you want to match strictly only those letters, just drop the `*` from the pattern:

```
        if [[ $response == [yY] ]]; then
```

Finally,
all the `;` at line endings are unnecessary.
The purpose of `;` is to separate multiple statements on the same line.
Line breaks naturally serve as statement separators.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just for the sake of clarity, why are the double brackets necessary for the "if [[ $response == [yY] ]]" statement?

Comment: `[ ... ]` cannot match patterns like that. `[[ ... ]]` is more modern and sophisticated, it can do this.

Comment: Just make it a habit to quote all variable expansions. It's not worth it to save a few quote characters.

Comment: @200_success I guess you're right. I dropped that point about quoting