# Bash script that checks if font is installed and installs it if necessary

Tags: bash, linux, shell, sh, installer

This checks if a font is installed by using `fc-list` and `grep`. If the particular font is not installed, it offers to install it for the user. This snippet is part of a larger script that installs a particular Conky configuration along with all of its dependencies with minimal effort from the user.

#### Concerns

- I have to create the `FONT_INSTALLED` variable to avoid a "too many arguments" error by placing the code into the `if` statement, is there a better practice for handling this?
- To check if the font is installed, I check if the `FONT_INSTALLED` variable is a null `String` or not. Is this considered good practice? I know in languages such as Java a `String` is normally checked for length/content since the default value is "".
- I've seen that placing `> /dev/null` after a command that would normally have output hides the output. This seems slightly 'hacky' as I know commands such as `wget` have the `-q` or `--quiet` option to hide output. For commands that do not have such an option, what is the preferred method of hiding output?

I realize that I should not place semi-colons after each line as per the advice on my first question [first question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/88394/71559). I forgot to make the appropriate changes to this code snippet.

```
FONT_INSTALLED=$(fc-list | grep -i "roboto");
if [ -z "$FONT_INSTALLED" ]; then
    echo "The Roboto font is not currently installed, would you like to install it now? (Y/N)";
    read response
    if [[ "$response" == [yY] ]]; then
        echo "Installing the Roboto font to the ~/.fonts directory...";
        mkdir .fonts/Roboto/ -p && wget --quiet -O ~/.fonts/Roboto/tmp.zip http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/download/roboto && 
        unzip ~/.fonts/Roboto/tmp.zip -d ~/.fonts/Roboto/ > /dev/null && rm ~/.fonts/Roboto/tmp.zip 
        fc-cache -fv > /dev/null
        FONT_INSTALLED=$(fc-list | grep -i "roboto");
        if [ -n "$FONT_INSTALLED" ]; then
            echo "The Roboto font was sucessfully installed!";
        else
            echo "Something went wrong while trying to install the Roboto font.";
        fi
    else
        echo "Skipping the installation of the Roboto font...";
        echo "Please note that this Conky configuration will not work without the Roboto font.";
    fi
else
    echo "The Roboto font has already been installed.";
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - I have to create the FONT_INSTALLED variable to avoid a "too many arguments" error by placing the code into the if statement, is there a
>     better practice for handling this?

You mean this part:

> ```
> FONT_INSTALLED=$(fc-list | grep -i "roboto");
> if [ -z "$FONT_INSTALLED" ]; then
> ```

Instead of putting in a variable,
you could put the `$(...)` itself into the `if`.

A better way would be to leverage the exit of `grep` in the `if` directly:

```
if fc-list | grep -i roboto >/dev/null; then
```

But since you use this check twice in your code,
the best would be to put it in a function:

```
is_font_installed() {
    fontname=$1
    fc-list | grep -i "$fontname" >/dev/null
}
```

You could then use this in `if` statements like this:

```
if is_font_installed roboto; then
```

> - To check if the font is installed, I check if the FONT_INSTALLED variable is a null String or not, is this considered good practice? I
>     know in languages such as Java a String is normally checked for
>     length/content since the default value is "".

My previous point answers that: use the exit code of a command when that's all you need.

Btw, there are no real null values in Bash.
Null values are just empty strings.

> - I've seen that placing `> /dev/null` after a command that would normally have output hides the output. This seems slightly 'hacky' as
>     I know commands such as wget have the `-q` or `--quiet` option to hide
>     output. For commands that do not have such an option, what is the
>     preferred method of hiding output?

Placing `> /dev/null` means redirecting standard output to a black hole.
It's a fine way to hide output, it's not 'hacky'.
It's more verbose than using the `-q` flag, when such flag exists.
But often `> /dev/null` is more portable than using the `-q` flag,
as the flag might not be available in all implementations.
For example `grep -q` works fine in any Linux,
but won't work on some Solaris.
So if you want to make your script as portable as possible,
it's safest to use the longer `> /dev/null` instead.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) then rather than mixing `[` and `[[`, you should stick with one or the other, preferrably `[[`. See [What is the difference between test, [ and [[ ?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031)

You might also want to consider preferring `printf` over `echo` for a more robust approach. See this amazingly detailed analysis of [why `printf` is better than `echo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo).

Comment: Nice, and it's especially informative with the links!

Answer (score 2):

> To check if the font is installed, I check the FONT_INSTALLED variable

Since you are using `grep` a more straightforward way is to test its exit status (`$?`). It is 0 if some lines matched, and 1 if no line matched.

As a general recommendation, a font name shall be passed as an argument. Typing `Roboto` 12 times is not a good way to spend keystrokes. One day you may want to install another font.